# Docker - Sharing docker files with host?

Tags: docker, repository

I know this isn't common practice at all.

I'm trying to share a docker image repertory with an host directory.

Usually, you're doing this the reverse way host directory -> docker image directory with

```
docker run -v /hostdirectory/:/dockerimagedirectory/
```

Is there any way to get the same inverted result aka the image directory -> hostdirectory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to copy the repertory from container then mount it again to be sync with container changes.

```
docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container /host/path/target

docker run -v /host/path/target:/file/path/within/container
```

Comment: Already tried that. Unfortunately that causes rights problems within the container. (that's mostly why I try the other way =p)

Comment: Do you try [named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/)?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I'm trying to get a working environment to work.
As I don't want to work with emacs/vim, I'm trying to share my var/www/ in order to edit my files easily with Sublime (or Brackets).

There's nginx, php7.0 and a symfony2 web directory. (this directory have rights problems when it comes to launch some commands with composer)

As I'm kinda new in all thoses things, and despite reading all mans about docker, nginx, etc, I still get some rights problems that I was trying to solve by looking for a reverse shared directory solution.

Comment: I'm still not sure how named volumes could solve the problem.

Comment: Do you want to use your docker as a development platform?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do =p

Comment: Docker is more for packaging purposes. It's easyier to use a full VM for dev and dockerized your project when everything is fine: https://github.com/denderello/symfony-docker-example